# The fastest way pandas can compile numerous dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am compiling some dataframes with pandas at the moment, currently 99 workbooks with around 200,000 rows of data and a few columns. The exercise is filtering one of these columns and getting a combined workbook of all of the filtered data.

Initially I used a list to append all the filtered data to one dataframe and then write out a the resultant csv, below:

```
appended_data=[]
for fname in os.listdir(readpath):
    if 'xlsx' in fname:
        ex_wbk = os.path.join(readpath + fname)
        try:
            fName = os.path.join(readpath + "\\" + fname)
            fBase = os.path.basename(fName)
            df = pd.read_excel(fName, index = False, index_col=None, na_values='')
            df.drop(df.iloc[:, 2:4], inplace = True, axis = 1) 
            df.dropna(subset=['Data Line'], inplace=True)
            appended_data.append(df)
            errorbook = ex_wbk
        except OSError:
            print(str(errorbook) + " Workbook in use")
            pass

appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, sort=True)
appended_data.to_excel(home, header=False, index=False)
```

***This took 789 seconds to run***

---

Then, I thought about making a csv file of each workbook with only the filtered data and compiling all of those. As below,

```
for filename in os.listdir(homedir):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        fName = os.path.join(homedir + "\\" + filename)
        fBase = os.path.basename(fName)
        fRaw = os.path.splitext(fBase)[0]
        df = pd.read_excel(fName, index = False)
        df.drop(df.iloc[:, 2:4], inplace = True, axis = 1) 
        df.dropna(subset=['Data Line'], inplace=True)
        df.to_csv(path_or_buf=home, header=True, index=False)

all_files = glob.glob(homedir + "/*.csv")
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files))
os.path.join(path, "*.csv")
df.to_csv ("D:\\Users\\cdoyle\\Desktop\\short\\combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

***This took 610 seconds to run***

---

Is there a faster way than the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever [profiled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) your code? Without it, you won’t really know where you'll get the most benefits and it’s hard to make good guesses.

Still, I notice that you’re reading a spreadsheet and *only after* it’s loaded in memory discarding a couple of columns. You’ll likely get some improvement if you already delegate that earlier, to the reader:

```
column_indices_to_preserve = […]
pd.read_excel(…, usecols=column_indices_to_preserve)
```

This will prevent you from doing at least one extra pass over the data, which is desirable. It will also reduce the memory footprint of each data structure.